# How to create a List of Lists in Scala in functional programming style

Tags: scala, functional-programming, purely-functional

I want to create a function in Scala that given a `List[Int]` returns a `List[List[Int]]`. For example `getCombs(List(1,2))` should returns `List(List(1), List(2), List(1,2))`.

I'm studying functional programming so I would like to accomplish my task using that paradigm.

I've created the following function and it works, but I think that there exist a better way to do the job in a functional programming style.

```
def getCombs(coins: List[Int]): List[List[Int]] = {

  var l = List(coins)
  var i = 0
  for (i <- 1 to coins.length - 1) {
    var it = coins.combinations(i)
    while (it.hasNext) {
      val el = it.next
      val newL = el :: l
      l = newL

    }

  }
  return l
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I first create a range of all the lengths of combinations that I want to make, then I use `flatMap` to create all the combinations and make a list out of them:

```
def allCombinations(list: List[Int]): List[List[Int]] = {
    (1 to list.length).flatMap(list.combinations(_)).toList
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(1 to coins.length).flatMap { 
  coins.combinations(_)  
}.toList
```

Comment: This returns a `List[Iterator[List[Int]]]`.

Comment: I changed the map to a flatMap...seems better to correct the code than give @Dima 's answer a down vote. :-)

Comment: Thanks, @KeithPinson. Some people just have to be like that ... :)